# Creating a dynamic 2nd chart from clicked data in 1st chart using D3.js (almost, but not quite)

Tags: svg, d3.js

Dual chart rendering from click event using absolute references.

Comment: As another note, if I create the new SVG on each click event, it essentially does what I need it to do, but the SVG is not overwritten.   Instead it just duplicates the bar chart under the previous versions...is there a way to replace the contents of the second SVG by clicking on the first SVG?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dcryan22/gDH7K/ I see that the bar chart is creating new bars with new y-Axes that overlap. Do you want there to be a SINGLE bar that changes upon selections or MULTIPLE bars that all scale to the single y-axis?

Comment: Thanks for translating to jsfiddle...I have yet to master that... I am attempting to do the latter.   I would like the bar chart to re-scale based on selections.   The next step will be to add a selection pane...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution....not elegant, but create white background and use absolute positioning to overwrite:

```
                 //Click feature added to show bar chart data
                    .on("click", function(d) {
                        d3.select(this)
                          .transition()
                          .attr("fill", "red");

                       var svg2 = d3.select("#container2")                               
                                    .append("svg:svg")                
                                    .attr("width", w2)
                                .attr("height", h)
                                    .style("position", "absolute")
                                    .style("background-color", "white");
```